# Can Logic Pro X scripts access the file system or load scripts from outside of Logic?

Tags: javascript, logic-pro-x

Is there any way to load an external script from within a Logic Pro X script?

Comment: I did not downvote but your question (as written) sounds like a "Can someone use Google for me 'cos I don't want to check the manual or search articles with possible solutions"... You can't write one line and call it a **programming** or technical question.

Comment: That's fair, I should have noted the research and trial and error I've been through.  The docs Apple provides for this functionality are pretty low quality.

Answer (score 2):

No, currently there is no way available to execute or `require/import` external Javascript files directly within a Logic Pro X script (most probably for security reasons). As a Logic Pro isn't a browser environment, you can't include script files from neither the local file system nor the web using a `<script>` tag. Even `document.createElement()` of the document object is unavailable for the same reason.

In short, Apple's implementation of the scripter runtime environment for the Logic Pro (X) does not allow to import/execute eternal Javascript files (as for now).